# Fast and safe way to save and retrieve data in java

Tags: java

In order to add data persistance to an oriented billing software, i wonder what is the best way to save and retrieve data in my situation.

I work with JavaFX's TableView populated by custom objects (with many string, int, booleans, ...), each one representing one bill. The user must be able to add, read and edit data on the fly. Everything is stored locally, no need to use a cloud or something like.

I usually use serialization to write my objects, but is it a safe and fast way to store around 10.000 custom objects ?

Should i use XML, Serialization, a local database (with JavaDB ?) or ... ?

By fast, i mean that the user can write, and edit data. I have no problem with a small loading time when the app is launched.
By safe, i don't mean encrypted, it is safe in the "data won't get lost or corrupted" way.

Eventually if there are multiple solutions, why one over another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any persistence mechanism (flat file, relational db, nosql) can be safe if used as designed or unsafe if abused/misunderstood.  Your question is a very open ended question and can get very involved, or be very light.. it all depends.

Typically the choices come down to:

- flat file (say binary serialisation, csv, json or xml).  Very simple mechanism which takes effort to scale to large files and care must be taken when making changes to the code base; as changes could prevent older files from being readable.  One has also got to bare in mind when the data is written in relation to changes coming in from the user and the possibility of a machine crash.  ie there are not transactions and so data can corrupt, not a simple topic in its own right.  As for which format is best, well many a religious war has been fought over that but typically a textual format (json, xml or csv) has the advantage of being human readable which helps debugging/maintenance tasks.  XML and Json support nested structures which is an advantage over CSV.  As for performance, text manipulation typically slows the parser down by about 10x compared to a binary one.  However there are fast implementations and slow ones, and for 10k objects you are unlikely to notice the difference.
- relational database.  Very useful for apps that benefit from using relational queries (SQL), and a lot of effort has gone into making them transactional and robust to machine crashes.  They are generally the persistence mechanism of choice for large businesses and require some knowledge to setup and maintain the DB itself.  H2 is a very simple, low cost entry provider and Oracle is at the other extreme end of the spectrum.  Relational databases suffer from a domain mismatch, specifically Object design and SQL design do not map together without some effort from the developer.  They also typically suffer from scaling problems as they are not usually clusterable, not a problem for 10k rows.
- no sql databases (eg redis, cassandra, mongo, couch, neo4j). Generally not transactional, but they are often faster than the relational dbs and offer clusters from the get-go making them very robust.  They also support different data modelling paradigms such as graph, list, document making the NoSQL landscape much richer than the relational SQL one.

I assume that you are not working on a professional project and lack a mentor, so I will wrap up by suggesting that you focus on flat files first and then pick a DB product of some kind to experiment with (H2 is very good for learning relational products, and Mongo or Redis for ease of learning one of the NoSql products).

Answer (score 0):

You can use H2 database (http://www.h2database.com/), it's really convenient way to store data, and you can use embedded database this looks like

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
// add application code here
conn.close();
```

H2 creates file test in user home directory named test.db.

Answer (score 0):

Object serialization is safe. It's not particularly fast and you have to be very careful about how you make changes to the class to ensure that you can consistently deserialize. This is the biggest disadvantage in my opinion about object serialization.

XML (or JSON) aren't bad either. There are binding technologies like JAXB, Jackson or Gson which allow you to seamlessly map objects to XML or JSON. Permissive binding makes these formats easier to use than object serialization, having the additional benefit of being human readable and editable, but with the cost of being more verbose (consider file compression). If your storage format is a giant XML file, you can also search for records using XPath.

JavaDB (or H2 or SQLite) is good in that it implements a relational data store, so you can perform SQL queries on the data. Managing lots of records is much more straightforward with a proper database. You could probably save on disk space, too. I would recommend this approach.

Will there be multiple clients reading these files? In that case, for safety, you would have to implement some kind of file locking scheme to prevent data corruption. You can get around this with some kind of out-of-process data management, using a lightweight server such as H2 or one of the NoSQL datastores like Mongo or Cassandra.